# Key bindings for navigating through selection regions

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

When you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, enter some search query and click on `Find All` (or hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>), Sublime Text 3 will find and select all occurrences of searched term found in current document. It will even count then, writing `X selection regions` in status bar.

I'd like to add a functionality, where pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> moves cursor to previous selected region, while pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> moves it to the next selected region.

I know how to modify Sublime Text 3's key bindings and add own keyboard shortcut, but I have no experience with selection regions in ST3 API, so I don't even know, where to start.

Can someone help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your own shortcuts:

1. Open menu Preferences > Key Bindings - User
2. Add these lines:

```js
  { "keys": ["alt+right"], "command": "find_next" },
  { "keys": ["alt+left"], "command": "find_prev" }
```

3. Save

That's it, now you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> to move cursor to previous selected region and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> to move it to the next selected region